# Node.js flush socket after write

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm implementing a tcp protocol in Node.

Full source:
https://github.com/roelandmoors/ads.js/blob/master/ads.js

specs:
http://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tcadsamsspec/html/tcadsamsspec_amstcppackage.htm?id=17754

The problem is that I use this to send a package:

```
this.tcpClient.write(buf);
```

If I send multiple commands, then multiple commands are combined into a single tcp packet.
This doesn't work.

There are more questions about this on SO, but they recommend using a delimeter.
But since I can't change the protocol this isn't an option.

Isn't there a simple solution to flush the socket?

socket.setNoDelay() doesn't help.

Edit: I also tried to use the drain event to send the next write, but the event is never called?

**Update:**

This seems to solve the problem, but is very uggly and I don't now if it always works.
Instead of writing it directly I write to a buffer:

```
this.writeFILO.push(buf);
```

Every cycle(?) I'm writing a package to the socket stream:

```
var sendCycle = function(ads) {
    if (ads.writeFILO.length > 0) {
        ads.tcpClient.write(ads.writeFILO.shift());
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        sendCycle(ads);
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: By default `.setNoDelay()` defaults to true according to documentation. To make this more efficient you could try creating and keep track in a queue/list of buffers to send and listening for `drain` events of the socket move to next one. Probably you write to fast to socket so TCP merges everything and sends. One other option is to spawn processes which create TCP connection and communicate with service like firefox does when attempts to load a webpage.

Comment: The doc means .setNoDelay() is the same as .setNoDelay(true) but is not active by default. I didn't had success with the drain event.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but I think Phoenix has a point. Being that TCP is a transport layer protocol and you're writing application layer code I'm not sure this will even work with node streams as they use TCP. At this point you're basically implementing TCP on top of TCP. I would use the node UDP sockets and just manage the buffers and ACKs yourself. It sounds like one way or another you're going to have to implement logic that acts along those lines anyways.

Comment: I don't understand that. UDP and TCP are 2 different things. I just want to send TCP packets,  but node combines them.

Comment: The only solution I see is to implement it with https://www.npmjs.org/package/raw-socket but then I have to write the TCP stuff. Seems like reinventing the weel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I refer to [the `socket.write(data, [encoding], [callback])` API](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback):

> The optional callback parameter will be executed when the data is finally written out - this may not be immediately.

So, set up a queue (array is fine) which holds messages to be sent.
When the above callback is being called, check the queue and send if needed..

This however does **not** guarantee what you're looking for, you'll have to test. Unfortunately the docs don't explicitly state when there's an acknowledgement from the remote end point that it actually received that message...

In the end, as you concluded, TCP is a **stream**.

An interesting idea which just came up to me now, however, if you're **FORCED TO** use an existing protocol, then open two TCP connections.
When one connection acknowledges (whatever the higher-level protocol is) receiving that message, send the next through the other one... and so forth..

Anyway, nice challenge :)

Answer (score 1):

I was wrong. TCP is a stream and the protocol works like a stream, but I didn't handle it like a stream.

PS: sending seperate messages seemed to work with setImmediate()

Comment: What is this `setImmediate()` i can't find anything out about it?

Comment: @Barkermn01 well, it was very well documented. Just found a lot of posts from 2019 and pior, also from the very first NodeJS documentation alive (v0.10.x back in 2013), so whatever xD

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, and I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are looking for, but there is a way to flush a socket in node. First you need to implement a Transform class.

See here for example: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream.

Then you can take your stream and pipe it through your transform before piping it into your socket.

I do not own this node module but I have seen an example of this here: https://github.com/yongtang/clamav.js/blob/master/index.js#L8