# Is there anyway to prevent TCP from merging packets on NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a school project to implement some algorithm where I can dynamically change the rate of packets I send from my client to my server by increasing or decreasing based on packet loss.

The problem is that it only works until it send 4 packets per time, then, it starts merging packets and sending them together, so I'm not able to determine if there were a packet loss.

Is there anyway I can prevent TCP from doing that behaviour?

**Client code:**

```
const net = require('net')

const PORT = 8550
const HOST = '127.0.0.1'

const client = new net.Socket()

client.setTimeout(1000)

let windowSize = 1
let sentPackets = 0

client.on('error', () => {
  console.log('Finishing connection...')
  process.exit()
})

client.connect(PORT, HOST, () =>
  console.log('Connected to ' + HOST + ':' + PORT)
)

client.on('connect', () => {
  sendPackets()
})

client.on('data', data => {
  sentPackets++

  if (sentPackets >= windowSize) {
    windowSize *= 2
    sentPackets = 0
    sendPackets()
  }
})

const sendPackets = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < windowSize; i++) {
    const message = (i + 1).toString()

    client.write(message, err => {
      if (err) console.log(err)
    })
  }
}

client.on('timeout', () => {
  windowSize /= 2
  sentPackets = 0
  sendPackets()
})
```

**Server code:**

```
const net = require('net')

const PORT = 8550
const HOST = '127.0.0.1'

const server = net.createServer()

server.on('error', err => console.log(error.toString()))

server.listen(PORT, HOST, () =>
  console.log('Servidor listening to ' + HOST + ':' + PORT)
)

server.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('data', data => {
    console.log('Received: ' + data.toString())

    socket.write(data)
  })

  socket.on('error', err => {
    console.log(err.toString())
  })
})
```

I know it gathers packets because when of the following output from server:

> Received: 1
>   Received: 1
>   Received: 2
>   Received: 1
>   Received: 234

And then it follows the same sequence.

Comment: A TCP connection is generally considered as a stream from server and client side (underneather it does use IP packets). In order to separate higher-level/application-level packets you might use a header that indicates how long each packet is or use some kind of separator. You might take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22414353/node-js-flush-socket-after-write for inspiration, it seems to be somewhat of the same challenge.

Comment: With TCP, you don't directly control how the data you send is grouped into packets or exactly how it's delivered.  If you need to keep it separated into some sort of unit like that, then you have to do that at the application level with some sort of demarcation in the data that you can sort out upon delivery or use a protocol on top of TCP like webSocket or socket.io that does it for you.

Comment: FYI, for sending data, TCP has a built-in delay process when you send a small piece of data, it waits a short time to see if there is more data coming so TDP can combine those into a common packet.  You can disable that in nodejs with [socket.setNoDelay()](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setnodelay_nodelay).

Comment: But, even if you use `setNoDelay()` you can't count on packets arriving in exactly the same pieces that you sent them in.  That's TCP.  TCP is allowed to coalesce small pieces of data into a larger packet (which generally makes things more efficient).

Answer (score -1):

Sir,

`TCP` is stream oriented protocol. What means it is sending and receiving a stream of bytes. Boundary of the written payloads is not preserved. What's more `TCP` already has congestion control build-in in its stack.

This is not a good choice of transport protocol for your project, unless you're implementing own version of `TCP/IP` stack. Because the congestion control implementation in OS stack is keeping its own send and receive windows and adjusts the transfer rate when needed. It is going to interfere with your intent to control it from an application.

Based on your example provided code, it seem you need capability to preserve message boundary. You may use plain old `UDP` to achieve that. There are other protocols too, like `SCTP`, `DCCP`, but they provide congestion control. It's also possible to use application layer protocol like `HTTP` or implement serialization mechanism (i.e. `protobuf`), but it's still going to operate over a TCP connection.

I suggest you use `UDP`. It is not reliable, just best effort delivery. However you can implement your own reliability mechanism that you can connect with the transfer control mechanism on top. For inspiration read how `TCP`, `DCCP` and `SCTP` are operating.